# php real_escape_string

Tags: php

I post the data of dynamically generated textbox in PHP. When I post the data using `real_escape_string()`, i.e:

```
$ingredient = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ingredient']);
```

...it doesn't post data from textbox and I use simple `$_POST[''];` method i.e:

```
$ingredient = $_POST['ingredient'];
```

...it gives me error when I use a single quote (`'`) in my text.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's', 'fgad', '55')' at line 2

this was my old post 
 i solved the problem locally by enabling `magic_quotes_gpc = On` but when upload this on my server it does't work again so how can i turn on magic quotes on server.

Comment: Sorry, what? What's the exact problem with using `mysql_real_escape`?

Comment: there is no error shown and when i checked the database table no record is inserted there

Comment: Check the return value of your `mysql_query` call. If it is false, you can find out why by printing out the return value of `mysql_error`.

Comment: Not enough info for meaningful advises. -1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this might be related to the "magic" quotes feature -- see this page for details: [Magic Strings & SQL](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-magic-quotes.php)

Basically, because of problems with SQL injection attacks, they pre-escaped strings with quotes after a certain version of PHP (I think it was 5.0, but I could be wrong). So the end result is that now your software has to check for the software version and behave differently depending on whether the string is already escaped or not.

Comment: Magic quotes were added in 4.0 (2001, almost a decade ago) and officially deprecated at least 2 or 3 years ago.

Comment: Could you please give a little more information regarding the error on the server?

Comment: Just curious, if this is the accepted answer, why the -1?
(I don't really mind it, I'm just new to the site so I want to learn why certain situations happen. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an open database connection? `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a MySQL server to talk to in order to function.

Comment: ofcourse it have cause when i add through simple $_POST[''] it adds the record to the database

Comment: @hunter You need the open connection **at the time you call `mysql_real_escape_string`**. If you open the connection afterwards, it won't work.

Comment: i have a database connection on top of my page

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
$ingredient = $_POST['ingredient'];

$ingredient = mysql_real_escape_string($ingredient);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

you must used connection db see
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

you can use also
     string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr )